# Can not send email from codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter, email

I have seen the same question on this and many other websites but the solutions they gave do not work for me. So i am asking again.

To send mail i wrote the following code

```
<?php

class Email extends CI_Controller{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password' 
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('mymail@gmail.com', 'mymail bcc');
    $this->email->to('mymail@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('This is a test email');
    $this->email->message('Oops This is Great.');

    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Your email was sent';       
    }

    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
       }
       }
```

I installed openssl and also uncommented the line extension=php_openssl.dll from php.ini. But i get the following erros

```
  An Error Was Encountered

   220 mx.google.com ESMTP qp6sm2730344pbc.55

    hello: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [119.30.39.78]
    250-SIZE 35882577
     250-8BITMIME
     250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH
     250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

     from: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
     530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 qp6sm2730344pbc.55

     The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn
      more          at          
     530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 qp6sm2730344pbc.55

     to: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
     530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 qp6sm2730344pbc.55

     The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. 
     Learn more at 
     530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 qp6sm2730344pbc.55

     data: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 
     http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 qp6sm2730344pbc.55

     The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
      530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 qp6sm2730344pbc.55
     502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. qp6sm2730344pbc.55
     The following SMTP error was encountered: 502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. qp6sm2730344pbc.55
     Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send
      mail using this method.
```

When i use parent::CI_Controller(); i get a fatal error Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::CI_Controller() in C:\wamp\www\test\application\controllers\email.php on line 6
Though i am using php 5.4.3

Please let me know what i am missing here.

Comment: I don't see `parent::CI_Controller()` call in your example, however that syntax have been deprecated since php5.0. The example's `parent::__construct();` is the new syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in [Mail](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) class uses the key names `smtp_user` and `smtp_pass` for smtp credentials.

Change the `username` and `password` params in your `$config` array to `smtp_user` and `smtp_pass`.

Comment: Now i am getting lots of errors, following are some of the errors                                                                             A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1689
A PHP Error was encountered

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Sounds like a network problem, does it work with non ssl `'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com'` and `'smpt_port' => 25`? I suspect that the ssl extension is acting up.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* SENDS EMAIL WITH GMAIL */

class Email extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //Do your magic here
    }

    function index()
    {
        $config = array(
            'protocol'  => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'mygmail@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '*********'
        );

        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        // $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Chirag');
        $this->email->to('mygmail@gmail.com');
        $this->email->cc('myanothergmail@gmail.com');   
        $this->email->subject('This is an email testing');
        $this->email->message('It\'s working, that\'s really awesome..!');

        if ($this->email->send()) 
        {
            echo "Your Email has been sent successfully... !!";
        }
        else
        {
            show_error( $this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }

}

/* End of file email.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/email.php */
```